# Как извлечь код с приватного проекта на GitLab?

Tags: git, api, gitlab

Нужно получить ссылку к файлу с приватного проекта на GitLab, которая открывает этот самый файл с кодом внутри. Если использовать обычный raw файла, то перебрасывает на страницу авторизации.
Я знаю, что это возможно сделать посредством API сервиса, но я не могу, потому что все мануалы по использованию API этого сервиса сфокусированы на linux, а я использую Windows.

**Edit:**
Из комментарий внизу помогли найти [статью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207644/open-a-file-directly-from-a-gitlab-private-repository/24210596#24210596) с похожей проблемой.
Нашёл нужный запрос, как я думаю.

> `https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/<project_id>/repository/raw_blobs/<file_id>?private_token=<your_private_token>`

Тут 3 поля:

> project_id
>
> file_id
>
> your_private_token

Из них мне только нужно теперь узнать file_id. Теперь главный вопрос — где его можно узнать для файла, что мне нужен? Как я и писал ниже в комментариях, предложенная статья не может мне помочь, потому что нужный мне файл лежит в 3 разделах вперёд, а не в главном.

Можно, конечно, переместить этот файл в корневой раздел проекта, но проблема в том, что он уже задействаван в нескольких десятках файлах проекта в коде. Мне было бы проще взять ссылку на содержимое этого файла.

Жду вашей помощи, господа!

Comment: [абсолютно кроссплатформенно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210596/4827341) — браузеры (в огромных количествах) имеются во всех современных операционных системах.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вроде тянет на ответ, если переведёте )

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, а где можно узнать этот <file_id>? Просто я на этот вопрос уже сегодня натыкался и попробовал этот ответ. У меня вышла ошибка `{message: "404 Blob Not Found"}`, скорее всего потому что не правильно указал file-id.

Comment: @darkmind187, узнать — из предыдущего запроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, но там нет id именно файла. Вся проблема в том, что мой файл лежит в 3 разделах вперёд. Этот запрос мне просто выводит название первого раздела, его id и т.п., но не файла, что мне нужен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, провёл микро-исследование. буду рад уточнениям/дополнениям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### приватное/публичное хранилище

насколько я понимаю, обращения к приватному хранилищу отличаются лишь тем, что к запросу требуется добавлять (в виде get-параметра) ваш частный токен (*private token*), который можно получить в настройках учётной записи на [закладке *access tokens*](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens):

```
https://gitlab.com/...?private_token=ваш_частный_токен
```

или, если в запросе уже есть другие параметры, то:

```
https://gitlab.com/...?параметр=значение&private_token=ваш_частный_токен
```

#### проекты

список своих проектов можно получить запросом:

```
$ curl 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=вчт'
..."id":идентификатор1,...
```

из всей информации интересен в данном случае только `id` проекта.

как найти идентификатор чужого публичного проекта (не делая его форка), я, увы не нашёл. поэтому сделал форк проекта https://gitlab.com/fdroid/repomaker и узнал, что его `id` равен `2895915`. вот его просмотром и займёмся.

#### файлы проекта

получить корневой каталог хранилища для этого проекта:

```
$ curl 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/2895915/repository/tree'
```

получить всё дерево файлов/каталогов хранилища можно, добавив параметр `recursive=1`:

```
$ curl 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/2895915/repository/tree?recursive=1'
```

чтобы эту json-структуру было удобнее просматривать, можете воспользоваться любимыми инструментами. я буду использовать *sed* и *grep*:

```
$ curl ... | sed 's/{/{\n/g' | grep чего-нибудь
```

#### содержимое файла

например, меня заинтересовал файл `tests/assert-test-confinement.sh`:

```
$ curl ... | sed 's/{/{\n/g' | grep assert
"id":"42203342afd85ab7c1d94d6b265572f81669fc3a","name":"assert-test-confinement.sh","type":"blob","path":"tests/assert-test-confinement.sh","mode":"100755"},{
```

чтобы вывести содержимое файла, понадобится его `id`:

```
$ curl 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/2895915/repository/raw_blobs/42203342afd85ab7c1d94d6b265572f81669fc3a'
```

получилось такое содержимое:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ ! -d "private_repo" ] || (echo "Error: Tests wrote in private_repo" && exit 1)
[ ! -d "media/user_1" ] || (echo "Error: Tests wrote in media/user_1" && exit 1)
[ ! -d "media/user_2" ] || (echo "Error: Tests wrote in media/user_2" && exit 1)
exit 0
```

вроде, всё верно.

---

#### дополнение

ещё можно указывать (с помощью параметра) нужную ссылку (*ref*) на ветку или метку (при получении дерева) с помощью параметра `ref_name`:

```
$ curl 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/2895915/repository/tree?recursive=1&ref_name=master'
```

ну и много чего другого делать, ознакомившись с [документацией](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/README.md) и уточняя детали в (кажется, не совсем) [соответствующих исходниках](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/spec/requests/api/v3).

Comment: То, что надо. Это решило мою проблему. Спасибо!

Comment: Прочитал исследование, вроде бы пока нечего добавить, кроме плюса. )

Comment: Кстати, вам уведомления из чата так и не приходят?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вроде, приходят.